# How to remove bulk rows of duplicated chars from string in Postgres or SQLAlchemy?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, duplicates, sql-update

I have a table with a column named "**ids**" , type of String. Could someone tell me how to remove the duplicated values in each of the rows?

Example, table is:

```
    --------------------------------------------------
    primary_key  |      ids
    --------------------------------------------------
        1        |  {23,40,23}
    --------------------------------------------------
        2        |  {78,40,13,78}
    --------------------------------------------------
        3        |  {20,13,20}
    --------------------------------------------------
        4        |  {7,2,7}
    --------------------------------------------------
```

and I want to update it into:

```
    --------------------------------------------------
    primary_key  |     ids
    --------------------------------------------------
        1        |  {23,40}
    --------------------------------------------------
        2        |  {78,40,13}
    --------------------------------------------------
        3        |  {20,13}
    --------------------------------------------------
        4        |  {7,2}
    --------------------------------------------------
```

In postgres I wrote:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET ids = (SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST(
    (SELECT ids FROM table_name)::text[]))
```

In sqlalchemy I wrote:

```
session.query(table_name.ids).\
    update({table_name.ids: func.unnest(table_name.ids,String).alias('data_view')},
           synchronize_session=False)
```

None of these are working, so please help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could improve the design by storing these ids in another table one id per row with a foreign key referencing `table_name.primary_key`.

Also storing Array data as text strings seems strange.

Anyway, here is one way to do it:  I wrapped the set returned by `UNNEST` with an inner subselect to be able to apply the aggregate_function needed to concatenate the strings again.

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET ids = new_ids
FROM LATERAL (
    SELECT primary_key, array_agg(elem)::text AS new_ids
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT primary_key, UNNEST(ids::text[]) as elem 
          FROM table_name ) t_inner  
          GROUP by primary_key )t_sub  
WHERE t_sub.primary_key = table_name.primary_key
```

Comment: Why `string_agg` and manually form an array literal, when there's `array_agg`?

Comment: @Ilja Everilä you are right: `array_agg()` and casting to varchar will do as well. Should I change it in the Answer? The OP did not show the table definition and the exact type of the column.

Comment: @ Clamp, thank you so much it worked! I was putting an example of my data, so I used "primary key" as the column name, so it looks like a bad design, thank you for pointing that out! @ Ilja Everilä  I think both array_agg and string_agg would work in my case, but since I don't need to sort my data, string_agg should be fine.